# Can AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW cause an EINVAL from fchmodat()?

Tags: c, posix

I'm reading the [fchmodat() POSIX function spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchmodat.html) and I'm unsure whether the following is correct:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int chown_test(const char* path, mode_t mode, mode_t new_mode)
{
#ifdef HAVE_FCHMODAT
    if (fchmodat(AT_FDCWD, path, new_mode,
                AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) && errno != EOPNOTSUPP)
        return 1;
#else
    if (!S_ISLNK(mode) && chmod(path, new_mode))
        return 1;
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

With `mode` being `st_mode` of `lstat(path...)`.

In other words, the above function is supposed to try to set mode of the file or symlink if the system supports that. If it doesn't, it should just return gracefully.

For that reason, I'm checking for `EOPNOTSUPP` error as specified by POSIX:

> [EOPNOTSUPP]
>
> > The AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW bit is set in the flag argument, path names a symbolic link, and the system does not support changing the mode of a symbolic link.

However, I'm a bit worried about `EINVAL` which is specified as:

> [EINVAL]
>
> > The value of the flag argument is invalid.

Theoretically, if a particular file system does not support setting mode bits of a symbolic link, I think that it could actually treat `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` as an invalid flag.

On the other hand, the `EOPNOTSUPP` error description and the way flags are described:

> Values for flag are constructed by a bitwise-inclusive OR of flags from the following list, defined in :
>
> AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW
>
> > If path names a symbolic link, then the mode of the symbolic link is changed.

make me think that this flag should always be treated by valid by a compliant implementations.

Am I correct or should I implement a fallback to `chmod()` in case of `EINVAL`?

---

*Edit*: as a note, I just found out that Linux returns `ENOTSUP` (which has the same value as `EOPNOTSUPP`) whenever `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` is used, even if the path *does not* name a symlink.

Comment: I read that as saying `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` is always a valid flag in conforming implemenatations.  Good question, though.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant text is XSH 2.3 Error Numbers:

> Implementations may support additional errors not included in this list, may generate errors included in this list under circumstances other than those described here, or may contain extensions or limitations that prevent some errors from occurring.

At first this seems to allow the behavior described. However I believe the text that follows just below:

> Implementations may generate error numbers listed here under circumstances other than those described, if and only if all those error conditions can always be treated identically to the error conditions as described in this volume of POSIX.1-2008. Implementations shall not generate a different error number from one required by this volume of POSIX.1-2008 for an error condition described in this volume of POSIX.1-2008, but may generate additional errors unless explicitly disallowed for a particular function.

renders an implementation that gives `EINVAL` for this condition is non-conformant. POSIX specifies `EOPNOTSUPP` as the error code for this condition, so an implementation "shall not" (this is a normative requirement) generate a different error code for it.

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_03

Comment: Err, on Linux `ENOTSUP` has the same value as `EOPNOTSUPP`.

Comment: I meant `EOPNOTSUPP`. I'll fix it.

Comment: @R: Why do you think Linux is broken?  Linux is not even mentioned in the question...

Comment: Sorry, I must have crossed my reading of this question with another one about Linux and thought the question was about some behavior Linux was exhibiting rather than a theoretical possibility. I've fixed my answer.